# Matlab cannot save figure with alpha correctly

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to create a figure which requires changing the transparency of one of the components of the plot, but when I try to save the figure it ends up saving part of the figure along with parts of the save dialogue that are on my screen at the same time:

[image: figure saved with alpha]

To set the alpha of part of my figure I'm using

```
sc=imagesc([-1 1], [-1 1], F);
alpha(sc, 0.75)
```

Constructing the figure without changing any alpha values results in the figure being saved correctly, but I end up with an incomplete figure. I've tried saving in `png` and `pdf` formats to no avail. How can I set the alpha so that things save properly?

Comment: are you using Matlab 2014b?

Comment: This is with 2014a on Linux.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this, using Matlab 2010b; using the clown-example (loading an image) and setting the alpha-value afterwards. The result I get is pretty much ok.

Comment: Which saving method are you using (e.g. from the menu, using `print`, etc) and which renderer?  It would be useful to know the output of `opengl 'info'`, too.

Comment: I decided to layer things in a different way instead of messing with the alpha.

Answer (score 0):

[Export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) saves figures to png whilst preserving transparency. Alternatively, save the transparent image programmatically, using imwrite.